# Shift layout programmatically - android

Tags: android, android-layout

I am implementing a approach where there is fragment and it contains the initial layout with some data. Now I want to shift that initial layout down if there is notification pops up and up if notification is gone. I am wondering how can I implement that ? How can I shift up and down the layout based on notification is available or not ?

Here is a design.
[layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ma5fm.jpg)

Image-A is the initial layout with no notification and Image-B is the layout after additional layout(notification) at top.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just have the notification always in the layout, but set its visibility to GONE when it shouldn't show.  That tells the layout to not show it and not take up any space for it.  Then when you want to show it, set it to VISIBLE.

Comment: How can I tell programmatically tell not to take up any space while it is not visible because if you make is invisible, then it will still left the space there on layout.

Comment: @Jeff You set it to GONE.  That's what GONE does-  it tells the system that the view is invisible and 0 size.  INVISIBLE means invisible but normal size, and VISIBLE means visible.

Comment: Oh so GONE. Do you recommend to have constraint layout so that one layout is constraint to another ? I will try that out soon. Thanks for your input @Gabe

Answer (score 0):

What you want to implement is called Banners and you can implement it using Motion layout, Here's more detail about them on [material components](https://material.io/components/banners)

Follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/@arekk/implementing-material-banners-using-motionlayout-c73e1432f5c6), you can implement it very easily.

Comment: Will that shift the existing layout or not ?

Comment: It'll, and read the docs for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can use animateLayoutChanges as true on your root layout (considering that notification and body layout are in the same file)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/notificationLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@color/orange_300"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- body here -->
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainBody"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="12dp"
        android:background="@color/blue_300"
        android:orientation="vertical" />

</LinearLayout>
```

When you change notificationLayout visibility (VISIBLE OR GONE), you will get the animation you want.